# A question about the past paticiple "inflicted"

Tags: word-meaning

Consider

1. The interference inflicted to the medical devices.
2. The interference inflicted by the mobile phones.

Now, we provide you with definition of the verb ***inflict*** from [Macmillan Online Dictionary:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inflict)

> *to cause something unpleasant to happen*

And Google Ngram result:

[image]

---

**Question:**

Given to the google result, Is it wrong or odd to use sentences like #1?

Comment: You might want to check the ngram for "inflicted on".

Comment: Another neat Google Ngrams trick is using "*" to see what word usually follows another word.  [Here's the Ngrams search for "inflicted *".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inflicted+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cinflicted%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binflicted%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binflicted%20at%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan What do you mean? Is it wrong to use #1 and #2 or they both are odd. It seems you want to say that preposition **on** is the best option.

Comment: Google Books: [penalties inflicted **on** them](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22penalties+inflicted+on+them%22):657 results; [penalties inflicted **upon** them](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22penalties+inflicted+upon+them%22):614 results. But [penalties inflicted **to** them](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22penalty+inflicted+to+him%22#tbm=bks&q=%22penalties+inflicted+to+them%22) ***did not match any book results***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked the wrong preposition.   That's all.

To my native ear, "inflicted to the medical devices" sounds nonsensical.   Since you're comparing it to "inflicted by the mobile phones", it looks like you though the preposition "to" would indicate the target of the interference.

That's a fair guess.   For other verbs, "to" can serve that purpose: "The damage caused to the medical devices" is one example.   However, not every verb uses the same set of prepositions for the same purposes.

As [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inflicted+on%2Cinflicted+by%2Cinflicted+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinflicted%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinflicted%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinflicted%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows, "inflicted on" occurs about twice as often as "inflicted by".   That is the natural choice for expressing your intended meaning.

There is nothing wrong or odd about the notion of "interference inflicted on medical devices by mobile phones".   There's also nothing strange about the notion of "interference caused to medical devices by mobile phones".   The only oddity is that the verb "inflicted" doesn't play nicely with the preposition "to".

The Macmillan entry that you've cited lists this common pattern of usage directly below its definition:

> inflict something **on** someone/something:  the environmental damage we are inflicting **on** the Earth [emphasis mine]

Comment: Many thanks. I came up with this wrong/odd collocations because I saw them in a scientific paper. Perhaps, the editor was not native or meticulous. I think It's a common defect in engineering papers.

Comment: Semantically, **interference** and **inflicted** do not play well together. It's like saying "Her meddling was inflicted upon them."

Comment: @TRomano Thank you, so do you prefer  using **interference** with **cause** ?

Comment: Those who have something *inflicted upon* them (pain, cruelty, malice, etc) are typically *sentient* creatures who *feel* and *endure* that which is inflicted upon them. These devices do not feel and endure interference; they fail or perform poorly because of it. **Interference** is the name given to unwanted meddling from outside. When a device behaves erratically, we say "That **is** interference" by which we mean "That behavior is *being caused by* something outside the device, meddling with its proper functionality". The malfunction is caused by the interference of another thing.

Comment: @TRomano I don't disagree with the comment about sentience, but the OP's comment mentioned "engineering papers" and it is quite common to use anthropomorphic language in some engineering fields, e.g. to talk about what an electrical device "sees" when "looking into" the input or output of whatever it is connected to. For example "... interference inflicted on a wireless communication device..." in [0026] and [0027] of this patent: http://www.google.ch/patents/WO2010129614A1?cl=en

Comment: The question of sentience aside, I would not use ** interference inflicted upon" unless it is a recognized term of trade. We could say  "... a method for minimizing *the effects of interference* upon a wireless device" or "a method of shielding a wireless device against interference", depending on the nature of the invention.

Answer (score 2):

The are both wrong because neither is a complete sentence. Aside from that, if we suppose that each clause is part of a complete sentence, then 2. should be fine since *by* indicates the source of the interference. 1. sounds strange. I cannot explain why. Natural sounding pairs in include "inflicted on" and "inflicted upon".

If this is part of some kind of scientific report, I can imagine the clause

> the interference **caused** by the mobile phones

being used. But I am not strongly advocating this. 2. seems good enough.

Comment: You are right, I should have written a complete sentence rather a clause.